# Vue Js not deploying to Firebase because of Eslint Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, eslint

I am getting this error for the past hours and i have not been able to resolve it. I have tried all the solutions online including uninstalling aslant globally and in the project and installing it again. Unfortunately the most common answer does not really apply in my case since my package.json file does not really have that file structure.

```
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .


/Users/KingdomMac/Downloads/ermnl-dashboard-master/functions/index.js
  22:71  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)


Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "vue-white-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "firebase": "^8.6.8",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.2",
    "vue-click-outside": "^1.0.7",
    "vue-clickaway": "^2.2.2",
    "vue-github-buttons": "^3.1.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.14.1",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-social-sharing": "^2.4.6",
    "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.11.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.5.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.20.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sass": "~1.32",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

Also my .eslintrc.js file

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": "plugin:vue/essential",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 13
    },
    "plugins": [
        "vue"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

And my index.js file

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

// exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
//   // Get user and add custom claim (admin)
//   const customClaims = {
//     admin: true,
//   };
//   return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then((user) => {
//     return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims);
//   }).then((authUser) => {
//     return {
//       message: `Success! ${data.email} has been made an admin.`,
//     };
//   }).catch((error) => {
//     return error;
//   });
// });

exports.addUserRole = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (authUser) => {
  if (authUser.email) {
    const customClaims = {
      admin: true,
    };
    try {
      let _ = await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(authUser.uid, customClaims);
      return db.collection("roles").doc(authUser.uid).set({
        email: authUser.email,
        role: customClaims,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});

exports.setUserRole = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth.token.admin) return
  try {
    let _ = await admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(data.uid, data.role)
    return db.collection("roles").doc(data.uid).update({
      role: data.role
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `"lint": "eslint ."` to `"lint": "eslint ",` in your package.json

Comment: I dont have that in my package.json. This is what I have in my package.json  `"lint": "vue-cli-service lint" `